# Can't store values from callback function into class variables : Swift

Tags: swift, asynchronous, callback

I have a callback function which retrieves stuff from a url however the information doesn't get stored into class variables.

```
var counts:Int?
var imagesComments : [NSArray] = []

loader.getFeed("1", completionHandler: { response in
        if let dataArr = response["content"] as? NSArray{
            for downloaded_images in dataArr{
                if let image = downloaded_images as? NSDictionary{
                    let url = image["url"] as? String
                    // Get images and load into images
                    if let comments = image["comments"] as? NSArray{
                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                            self.imagesComments.append(comments)
                        }
                    }
                    self.loader.downloadImage(NSURL(string: self.baseUrl+url!)!, completionHandler: { response in
                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                            self.images.append(response)
                            self.pileView?.reloadContent()
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    })
```

After this code is run, I have a place where I print imagesComments and counts and both are empty/nil

JSON File:

```
{
"success": true,
"message": null,
"content": [{
    "url": "6\/image_2.png",
    "date_added": "2015-12-02 22:43:05",
    "comments": ["Awesome Pic", "WOOHOOOOO THIS IS GREAT"],
    "likes": []
}, {
    "url": "2\/image_5.png",
    "date_added": "2015-12-01 06:43:48",
    "comments": ["EhHHHH"],
    "likes": []
}]
}
```

Comment: I was trying to cut the code down but didn't realize that it may lead to confusion. I have updated my code to show you everything as is. I also uploaded my JSON file. I can retrieve everything and print out everything. For example, if I print(comments) before I append to imageComments, I can see the comments for that image.

Comment: I'd suggest you set a breakpoint inside this closure and single step through it and the problem will probably jump out at you. I tried it with your JSON, though, and it seemed to work. The main thing that bothers me is that you're updating `imagesContents` and `images` is separate dispatch calls, so they could easily be out of sync when you call `reloadData`. But I'm assuming you problem is more fundamental than that. When you say, "After this code is run, ... I print imagesComments." Are you sure you're not just hitting that code before all of this asynchronous stuff had a chance to finish?

Comment: I make sure the asynchronous stuff is finished. I have another variable in the class that is called var images:[UIImage?] = []. For some reason when I self.images.append(response), it works completely fine. However, self.imagesComments.append(comments) doesn't. I tried to do breakpoints and  it goes to dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { self.imagesComments.append(comment)}. I just don't get why the imagesComments becomes null after the entire function is run.

and another thing, I don't even need dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { to append to images. it works without it.

Comment: It's hard to say on the basis of what's been provided, but given that you should avoid those two separate `dispatch_async` calls (unless you _really_ have code that allows these two arrays to be out of sync), I'd put the `self.imagesComments.append(comments)` inside the same `dispatch_async` where you `self.images.append(response)`. That's the only weird thing here that I can see. If that's not it, then the problem rests elsewhere (e.g. where you're examining these arrays, something lingering about that's resetting one of these arrays, etc.).

Comment: Yea, I really think its my code. After the code runs, it kind of refreshes the ViewController without my knowledge. I don't know why this happens but it is happening. I am going to try and see what I can do for now.